# RDS storage 100% usage but no data recorded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a free tier account which meant I could only have 20 GB storage. But I only created a few tables on my 2 rds(same region and same vpc) and no data stored yet but my storage usage is 100% already— I already received a notif that I’m already getting billed.

Is there any way to free up some storage space to lessen the storage usage??? I do not want to increase the storage space and only want to use for free tier.

Comment: 2 RDS instances? Each one having 20GB of space?

Comment: 1 rds has 5 GB and another one has 200 GB both been set up on a free tier use case.

Comment: The [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free) includes 20GB of storage for the first 12 months. If you have exceeded a total of 20GB provisioned storage, then you will be charged for the excess (`$0.115 per GB per month`).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> 1 rds has 5 GB and another one has 200 GB both been set up on a free tier use case

That's why you are charged. In RDS you can have 750 hours and 20 GB of storage "free" per month. This is **cumulative**. Your two RDS instances count toward 750 hours, not each one separately. The same goes for storage. You are cleary exceeding the limits with 205 GB it total, instead of 20 GB allowed. Check [aws docs](https://aws.amazon.com/free/):

[image]